# Why does my ajax post.request call my method, but doesn't do anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this Ajax request, but anyway, I still get `$.ajax({type: POST, url: add_timespan, data: {to_find_id: 192148455}, success:function(){alert(1);}});`

The thing is:

```
Started POST "/subgroups/519716477/add_timespan" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 14:54:44 +0200
Processing by SubgroupsController#add_timespan as */*
  Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"192148455", "subgroup_id"=>"519716477"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 702273327]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

As you can see, it starts my method, and even passes the params, but it does not finish it, as it does not add a timespan to my subgroup.

I can't find out why.
Can you help me?

EDIT:
As [Paul Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877472/paul-richter) mentioned, here's my controller Method:

```
def add_timespan
    RTimespan.create(timespan_id: params[:to_find_id].to_s, subgroup_id: @subgroup.id.to_s)
end
```

And as [arieljoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod) mentioned:
Yes I have a before filter:

```
before_action :set_subgroup, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,  :remove_admin, :search_user, :remove_user, :process_add_user, :process_add_admin]
before_action :login_required
```

I have edited my before_action to also have :add_timespan.

```
before_action :set_subgroup, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,  :remove_admin, :search_user, :remove_user, :process_add_user, :process_add_admin, :add_holiday]
before_action :login_required
```

Now I don't have the redirect anymore, but now it says:

```
Started POST "/subgroups/519716477/add_timespan" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 15:28:24 +0200
Processing by SubgroupsController#add_timespan as */*
  Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"310026848", "subgroup_id"=>"519716477"}
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 702273327]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 0ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subgroup without an ID):
  app/controllers/subgroups_controller.rb:161:in `set_subgroup'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `reset_timezone_to_utc'
```

set_subgroup method:

```
def set_subgroup
  @subgroup = Subgroup.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

EDIT:
I commented the `before_action :login_required` out. You know which error I get now?
The same as before? I'm starting to get desperate.

@[kirti-thorat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat): I have tried your Idea, but it does still not work.
When I use your Idea, I'm back to the first Log from line 4.
Do you have any other suggestions?

For further information: 
[LINK TO MY RAILS-FORUM POST](https://railsforum.com/topic/1698-whats-wrong-with-my-jqueryajax/)

Comment: Lets see your controller method code.

Comment: do you have some before_filter that might be redirecting you somewhere? maybe a user related before_filter? that's what the log says

Comment: Arieljuod is right; it looks like your `login_required` is most probably causing the redirect. But I don't quite understand your last edit, what change did you make to the `before_action`, specifically (in what way did you add the `:add_timespan` method)?

Comment: Also post the code for `login_required` - the other callback wasn't called until you've added it (and you need to add it)

Comment: Are you passing the authenticity_token in the Ajax request?

Comment: @PaulRichter: I have added the changes I made to my before_action.

Comment: You're not passing 'id' in the ajax request.  It's used to load the subgroup.

Comment: Where should I add it? Just as the other data in data: {id: 192148455}

Comment: Do you need to load the sub_group? If not, then you want to remove :add_timespan from the before_action.

Comment: Yes, i think I need to, as `add_timespan` creates a relation between the actual subgroup, and a timespan.

Comment: Ok, then yes, add it in and I think you'll be back at your original issue which is either to do with the fact the user isn't logged in or you're not passing the authenticity_token in the ajax request.

Comment: Yes. I'm back to the original issue.
Now I get the first Log again. Do you know, how I pass the authenticity_token?

Comment: look in your log file, and see what happens when the ajax request comes in.

Comment: Comment out the before_action :login_required and test.  That'll eliminate if it's the login_required filter that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hello everybody, I've added some replies to your comments in the newest edit, below the horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

Update `set_subgroup` to resolve the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subgroup without an ID)`:

```
def set_subgroup
  if params[:id].present?
    @subgroup = Subgroup.find(params[:id]) 
  elsif params[:subgroup_id].present?
    @subgroup = Subgroup.find(params[:subgroup_id]) 
  end 
end
```

As per your params hash, you are getting `subgroup_id` for `SubgroupsController#add_timespan` request.

```
Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"310026848", "subgroup_id"=>"519716477"}
```

In this case you will need to pass `params[:subgroup_id]` in order to find matching `Subgroup` record.

Comment: Hello Kirti, thanks for your advice, but it still does not work. Now I get the redirect again.

Comment: Can you share the new server log, i.e., after making the change suggested by me.

Comment: It's the same as the first in the post... Just the highest log with `Started POST "/subgroups/519716477/add_timespan" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 14:54:44 +0200
Processing by SubgroupsController#add_timespan as */*
  Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"192148455", "subgroup_id"=>"519716477"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 702273327]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`